# Use Ansible 2.12 to access AWS EC2 via host: tag class

Tags: ansible, amazon-ec2

On my local hardware, I have a Vagrant box running Ubuntu 20, on which I'm using Ansible 2.12.2

I am able to access AWS and even create an EC2 instance within a VPN.

When I view inventory, I can see the EC2 server as:

```
"ec2-64-135-69-12.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com": {
    ...,
    "tags": {
        "Details": "File server and api",
        "Name": "File server via Ansible",
        "OS": "Ubuntu20",
        "Type": "Image Server",
        "class": "classfileserver2022"
    },
    ...
},
```

In my next playbook, I can access the server via

```
hosts: "ec2-64-135-69-12.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
```

But I would prefer to access it by any of the tags in the json above.

I have tried

```
hosts: "tags_class_classfileserver2022"
```

and

```
hosts:
  - tags:Class="classfileserver2022"
```

but I get errors like

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: tags_class_classfileserver2022
skipping: no hosts matched
```

How do I reach EC2 hosts using class tags?  (or any other tag..)

My playbook is as follows:

```
---
  - name: "Prepare base of {{ server_name }} box"
    vars_files:
      - vars/0000_vars.yml
      - vars/vars_for_base_provision.yml
      - vars/vars_for_geerling.security.yml
#    hosts: "ec2-54-153-39-10.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"   <-- this works
    hosts: "tags_Class_{{ tag_class }}"
    remote_user: ubuntu
    become: yes
    gather_facts: no

    pre_tasks:
    - name: Check for single host
      fail: msg="Single host check failed.  Try --limit or change `hosts` above."
      when: "{{ ansible_play_batch|length }} != 1"

    roles:
      - { role: geerlingguy.security }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider reading the section "Inventory plugins" in the [ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory.html#using-inventory-plugins).

> To start using an inventory plugin with a YAML configuration source, create a file with the accepted filename schema documented for the plugin in question, then add plugin: plugin_name. Use the fully qualified name if the plugin is in a collection.

```
# demo.aws_ec2.yml
plugin: amazon.aws.aws_ec2
```

> [...]
> You can create dynamic groups using host variables with the constructed keyed_groups option. The option groups can also be used to create groups and compose creates and modifies host variables. Here is an aws_ec2 example utilizing constructed features:

```
# demo.aws_ec2.yml
plugin: amazon.aws.aws_ec2
regions:
  - us-east-1
  - us-east-2
keyed_groups:
  # add hosts to tag_Name_value groups for each aws_ec2 host's tags.Name variable
  - key: tags.Name
    prefix: tag_Name_
    separator: ""
groups:
  # add hosts to the group development if any of the dictionary's keys or values is the word 'devel'
  development: "'devel' in (tags|list)"
compose:
  # set the ansible_host variable to connect with the private IP address without changing the hostname
  ansible_host: private_ip_address
```

> [...] You can use `ansible-doc -t inventory -l` to see the list of available plugins. Use `ansible-doc -t inventory <plugin name>` to see plugin-specific documentation and examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is what solved it for me, based on Panki's answer

```
# demo.aws_ec2.yml
inventory-plugins
plugin: amazon.aws.aws_ec2
regions:
  - us-west-1
keyed_groups:
  - key: tags.class    # <-- note: lowercase c
    prefix: tags_Class_
    separator: ""
```

Example playbook matching tags: class: uniqueclassname

```
# example_playbook.yml
---
  - name: "Playbook for {{ server_name }} EC2 instance"
    vars_files:
      - vars/0000_vars.yml
    hosts: "tags_Class_{{ tag_class }}"
    remote_user: ubuntu
    become: yes
    gather_facts: no

    roles:
      - { role: xxxxxxx }
```

Variables created alongside playbook:

```
# vars/0000_vars.yml
tag_class: "uniqueclassname"
server_name: "My Fancy Server"
```